# Setting php.ini max_file_size issue.

Tags: php, configuration

I'm having trouble editing my php.ini max_file_size to 20M. I can change it, save the document, but when I restart usbwebserver it simply changes it back to the default 2M.

Does anyone know of this problem and what causes it ?

Comment: Probably it's being overwriten in another place in your code... Run `phpinfo()` to see which config file is readed and make sure that you edit the right file. Also, I am not sure if "restart usbwebserver" will restart apache... you should restart apache to apply changes.

Comment: Restarting a webserver refreshes the files. Is it possible that you are modifying at the wrong place(locally) ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.

There were actually two php.ini files. One resides in my php folder and the other in the settings folder. Not sure why there are two, but editing both seems to do the trick.